# Hive: How to change name of a field, when it is used as a partition field?

Tags: sql, hive, nosql

I have a managed table stored on GCS which is partitioned by a field called `date`. So there are directories on GCS with `date=2017-01-01` format which are used to organize table data.

Now I want to change field name to `snapshot_date`. I cannot simply use `ALTER TABLE` command. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine

Comment: @Winteriscoming The link is for MS SQL. The question asks about Apache Hive.